# When will the next edition of Call of Cthulhu arrive?

Tags: call-of-cthulhu

When will the next CoC edition be released? If there hasn't been an official announcement, I'll take hints, rumours, experience with previous editions and calculations.

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is too specific to one moment in time. (The right answer will keep changing as delays and new editions happen.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, that's a good question.  Back in the day, [Chaosium cranked out a new version every 3 years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_of_Cthulhu_%28role-playing_game%29) whether it needed to or not - and usually it didn't; the actual changes from version 1 to version 6 are only noticable to experts. One answer is "who cares, get the current version, because the next one won't be much different."

Now, the versions started getting less frequent especially as Chaosium had financial troubles, and it seems like a lot of the activity now are other games licensing the IP (Trail, Shadows, Realms of Cthulhu). It's been 6 years since a new rev so they'd seem due. It does seem like they'd want to put out a Seventh Edition at some point if only to keep it in print and bring in a little money - but they [ran out of 6th Edition in May and decided to just reprint it](http://www.chaosium.com/article.php?story_id=468), so probably not for a while.  In general things are going very slowly for them (some months there's not even a R'lyeh Report; when there is it's largely unchanged from previous months).

Comment: @Graham See my more recent answer as well, please.

Comment: I picked up a copy of 6th Ed (having lost my 2nd ed copy) the only real noticeable difference was that the editing was worse and it was harder to find stuff.

Answer (score 12):

I've just found this Q&A, and seen that it's rather outdated, so, FYI:

> Dustin [Wright, of Chaosium] said **Chaosium expects Call of Cthulhu 7th
>   Edition to be published in 2013**, but there’s no firm date yet.

Source and (quite a lot of) further details: [**Inside Call of Cthulhu 7th Edition**, *July 24, 2012*](http://theunspeakableoath.com/home/?p=1024)

Comment: According to playtesters, although still backward compatible, the 7th Edition offers significant changes to certain mechanics and updates the game in a few undisclosed ways. Most reports I have been privy to have been positive.

Answer (score 3):

As this remains a live question, **physical** copies of *Call of Cthulhu* 7th edition continue to elude enthusiasts, backers and the general gaming population.

At time of writing, Rick Meints - President of Chaosium - states that:

> backers will be getting [...] items [from the Kickstarter] in their first shipment that
>   will ship in 2015

This includes:

- Investigator Handbook
- Keeper’s Rulebook
- Keeper’s Pack: keeper’s screen, 3 map set, adventure booklet, keeper reference, character sheets, and floorpans
- Nameless Horrors
- S. Petersen Guide to Lovecraftian Horrors

Anyone can get access to electronic copies of *Investigator Handbook*, *Keeper’s Rulebook* and *Nameless Horrors* via the Chaosium store and other purveyors of electronic media.